# one way audio scenario

Tags: h.323

I have a setup

```
Server1------Server2--------Server3
```

We have h323 trunking between the all servers.
Call is initiated from server 1 to server2 which CFNA's it to server3.
On seeing the traces I observed ,during the inital OLC from server3 to server2.
Server2 doesnt send any OLC ACK to Server3.And Server3 sends a CLC to server2.

At this point i had attempted to initiate a faststart procedure.Which got rejected because
my server2 didnt send the OLC ACK ,for the OLC i recieved from Server3.
After this all the new OLC's from Server3 have a slowstart.

Could this be a reason for one-way audio? Absence of faststart in rest of the OLC's??

Answer (score 0):

This question does not make a lot of sense to me.  Fast Connect (aka, fastStart) is used to establish media channels (media flows) more rapidly.  The calling device will offer one or more channels (usually different voice codecs) and the called device can accept whatever channel(s) are appropriate.  Usually, there is a forward and reverse logical channel proposed and accepted, though a called device is not obligated to accept both directions.

So, what are you seeing in the initial Fast Connect exchange, exactly?  Is Server 3 accepting only one OLC in the SETUP?  (And I assume these are all forwarded by Server 2 from Server 1.)

I assume Fast Connect did not actually happen, since one does not send an OLCAck in response to a fastStart element.  One send a response fastStart element, instead.  So, I assume the call proceeds using normal H.245 signaling.

Since the call originates at Server 1, why would Server 2 send an OLCAck?  Is it a gateway device or just an intermediary that passes along signaling?  Did Server 1 send an OLCAck?